# errors when putting a function inside setInterval()

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

I have written this code in nodeJs:

```
function ricarica() {

   request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           var json = JSON.parse(body);
           //console.log(json[11].nome_abbr);
           //console.log(json[11].valore); 

            app.use(function(req, res, next) {
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                next();
            });

            app.get('/valore', function(req, res){
            res.json({ livello: json[11].valore }); 
            });     
        }
   });
}
```

I want to run that function every 10 minutes, i have looked at setInterval but when i replace this:

```
ricarica();
```

with this:

```
 setInterval(function() {
     ricarica();
 }, 600000);
```

When I ask for the data from my website, with the first I can see the data but It is not updated, with the second one I have the message"Cannot GET /valore";

How can i fetch data and update every 10 minutes?

Comment: _with the second one i have an error_: what error? what is the network status and the body of the response?

Comment: A loop will fail if the node program ends for some reason. Personally I would use a cron job or task scheduler entry to run the node.js script every 10 minutes so that it won't hog resources in the time between. Added benefit being that if the server restarts, you don't have to restart the node script either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved in this mode:

```
async function ricarica() {
while(true){
    await sleep(120000);
    request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var json = JSON.parse(body);
            var i;
            for(i = 0; i< json.length && json[i].nome_abbr != "PS_Giud" ; i++);
            console.log(json[i].nome_abbr);
            //console.log(json[i].valore); 

            app.use(function(req, res, next) {
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Accept, Content-Type, If-None-Match, X-If-None-Match");
                res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location, Warning, Etag");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, If-None-Match, X-If-None-Match, Authorization");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS");

                next();
            });

            app.get('/valore', function(req, res, next){
              res.json({ livello: json[i].valore }); 
            });     
        }
    });
}
```

}

and i have to call it only once

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function updateData() {
   ricarica();
}

function ricarica() {

   request.get(url, function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           var json = JSON.parse(body);
           //console.log(json[11].nome_abbr);
           //console.log(json[11].valore); 

            app.use(function(req, res, next) {
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
                next();
            });

            app.get('/valore', function(req, res){
            res.json({ livello: json[11].valore }); 
            });     
        }
   });
}

setInterval ( updateData, 600000 );
```

Comment: App.use seems to stop working when put in setInterval()